# Disable Ctrl-A shortcut in OSX / Firefox

Tags: macos, firefox, emacs, key-binding

OSX has Emacs keybindings on all text fields, that means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> takes you to the start of line.

In Firefox, sometimes, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> activates the "Highlight All" option of the Find bar, instead of taking me back to the start of the line.

Is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 2):

1. `System Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Keyboard Shortcuts` > `Application Shortcuts`
2. Click on the `+` button to add a new one, and fill the form in the popin like this:

   - `Application`: *Firefox*
   - `Menu Title`: *FooBar*
   - `Keyboard Shortcut`: Do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (it will show something like `^A`)
3. Click on `Add`.

You're done.

**EDIT**: unfortunately, you'll have to do this for every app for which you want to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (or any other keybinding).